# No available version of ghc-prim -any with GHC 7.2.2

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've got ghc-7.2.2 unknown linux tar.bz2 installed in `$HOME` on archlinux.

After installing a number of packages successfully with cabal-dev trying to install eg. parsec-numbers, text, ad etc I get:

```
cabal: cannot configure base-4.4.1.0 It requires ghc-prim -any
integer-simple and rts -any
There is no available version (of each of the above for example)
```

Is this an obvious fault in my installation or a possible bug?

I have the appropriate `$GHC_PACKAGES_PATH` set and have run ghc-pkg recache.

Here's my list of installed packages:

```
/home/jim/cabal-dev/packages-7.2.2.conf:
    QuickCheck-2.4.2
    bmp-1.1.2.1
    comonad-1.1.1.1
    comonad-transformers-2.0.2
    comonads-fd-2.0.2
    contravariant-0.1.3
    data-lens-2.0.2
    data-reify-0.6
    distributive-0.2.0.1
    free-2.0.2
    mtl-2.0.1.0
    primitive-0.4.0.1
    random-1.0.1.1
    repa-2.2.0.1
    repa-algorithms-2.2.0.1
    repa-bytestring-2.2.0.1
    repa-io-2.2.0.1
    semigroupoids-1.2.6
    semigroups-0.8
    transformers-0.2.2.0
    vector-0.9.1

/home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2/package.conf.d:
    Cabal-1.12.0
    array-0.3.0.3
    base-4.4.1.0
    bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
    (binary-0.5.0.2)
    bytestring-0.9.2.0
    containers-0.4.1.0
    directory-1.1.0.1
    extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.3
    ffi-1.0
    filepath-1.2.0.1
    (ghc-7.2.2)
    ghc-prim-0.2.0.0
    (haskell2010-1.1.0.0)
    (haskell98-2.0.0.0)
    hoopl-3.8.7.1
    hpc-0.5.1.0
    integer-gmp-0.3.0.0
    old-locale-1.0.0.3
    old-time-1.0.0.7
    pretty-1.1.0.0
    process-1.1.0.0
    rts-1.0
    template-haskell-2.6.0.0
    time-1.2.0.5
    unix-2.5.0.0
```

Yep, bytestring-0.9.0.2 should have been -0.9.2.0, apologies.

```
cabal-dev -v3 install bytestring --reinstall produces:

cabal-dev 0.9
built with Cabal 1.12.0
searching for cabal in path.
found cabal at /usr/bin/cabal
("/usr/bin/cabal",["--numeric-version"])
/usr/bin/cabal is version 0.10.2
Using cabal-install 0.10.2 at FoundOnSystem {locationPath = "/usr/bin/cabal"}
No sandbox specified. Using cabal-dev
Using cabal-dev as the relative cabal-dev sandbox
Using /home/jim/cabal-dev as the cabal-dev sandbox
Creating local repo /home/jim/cabal-dev/packages
searching for ghc-pkg in path.
found ghc-pkg at /home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg
("/home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg",["--version"])
/home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg is version 7.2.2
Using ghc-pkg 7.2.2
("/usr/bin/cabal",["--version"])
Complete arguments to cabal-install:
["--config-file=/home/jim/cabal-dev/cabal.config","install","--verbose=3","--reinstall"]
("/usr/bin/cabal",["--config-file=/home/jim/cabal-dev/cabal.config","install","--verbose=3","--reinstall","bytestring"])
searching for ghc in path.
found ghc at /home/jim/bin/ghc
("/home/jim/bin/ghc",["--numeric-version"])
/home/jim/bin/ghc is version 7.2.2
looking for tool "ghc-pkg" near compiler in /home/jim/bin
found ghc-pkg in /home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg
("/home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg",["--version"])
/home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg is version 7.2.2
("/home/jim/bin/ghc",["--supported-languages"])
("/home/jim/bin/ghc",["--info"])
Reading installed packages...
("/home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--global","-v2"])
("/home/jim/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--package-conf=/home/jim/cabal-dev/packages-7.2.2.conf","-v2"])
("/home/jim/bin/ghc",["--print-libdir"])
Reading available packages...
Resolving dependencies...
selecting
/usr/bin/cabal returned ExitFailure 1
```

Ha ha. Trying to catch the output with &2>file misses off "cabal: cannot configure bytestring-0.9.2.0. It requires ghc-prim -any...(same as before)"

Comment: Don't use cabal-dev for that, run cabal directly to have its output capturable. But don't forget the --dry-run.

Comment: Oh, and actually more interesting than why it wouldn't reinstall bytestring is why it believes it should. Which package were you trying to install when these errors appeared? `$ cabal install -v3 --dry-run that-package` would be nice.

Comment: cabal install -v3 --dry-run bytestring => cabal: cannot configure bytestring-0.9.2.0. It requires ghc-prim -any. There is no available version. IPkg ad depends on integer-simple [

Comment: cabal-install -v3 --dry-run ad => "cabal: cannot configure base-4.4.1.0. It requires ghc-prim -any, integer-simple -any and rts -any. There is no available version.."

Comment: I tried to build ghc-7.2.2 src (using my installed ghc-7.2.2 binary) with integer-simple but. ./configure overwrites the config.mk edit. I now find I cannot install ghc-7.2.2 src with integer-gmp either.

Comment: A second attempt produces the nonsense message:

"Configuring Cabal-1.12.0...
ghc-cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing

base >=4 && <3 && >=2 && <5
filepath >= 1 && <3
unix >= 2 && <=2.6"

make clean

A third attempt produces:

"Cabal-1.12.0...
ghc-cabal: Cannot find the program hs-colour at '' or on the path"

Comment: grep -r on the src tree returns config.mk and ghc.mk as the only references to integer-simple or $INTEGER_LIBRARY, ghc.mk has a conditional but I can't see where it's set.

Comment: Don't edit `config.mk`, you must edit `config.mk.in`. The `config.mk` is generated from that.

Comment: Reinstalling ghc-7.2.2-i386-unknown.linux.tar.bz2 produced an Error 2 which I hadn't noticed originally. make install => "utils/ghc-cabal/dist/install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal" install "/home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2/ghc" "/home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2/ghc-pkg" "strip" "/home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2" libraries/ghc-prim dist install (continued..)

Comment: '' '/home/jim' '/home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2' '/home/jim/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries' NO Installing library in /home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2/package.conf.d/package-cache: openBinaryFile:  does not exist (no such file or directory) make [1]*** [install packages] Error 1 make *** [install packages] Error 2 [

Comment: Despite the error, ghc had installed. I tried ghc-7.2.2-src.tar.bz2

Comment: Despite the error, ghc had installed. I tried ghc-7.2.2-src.tar.bz2  configure --prefix=$HOME/simple => "configure: building in-tree ghc-pwd \n /home/jim/lib/ghc-7.2.2/package.conf.d/package.cache openBinaryFile: does not exist...configure: Error: Building ghc-pwd failed" Tnx Daniel for the persistence.

Comment: Sorry, I've lost view of the situation. Can you update the question and lay out the situation, what's installed where, what's working, what isn't?

Comment: So the vanilla binary didn't create a package.cache file.

Comment: Sorry if I've missed describing some steps. From wiping my entire ghc installation I installed vanilla ghc-7.2.2-i386-linux-unknown.tar.bz2. I noticed the error messages in 6th and 7th previous comments. This installed a working copy of ghc but not cabal which behaves as per the OP. Ignoring this I tried installing the ghc-7.2.2-src.tar.bz2, configure failed as per the 3rd previous comment. HTH.

Comment: To repeat the experiment: apart from checking that I'd deleted all ghc including $HOME/share and removing $GHC_PACKAGE_PATH from .bashrc the vanilla ghc binary now installs fine. Will try and build an integer-simple version.

Comment: Okay, that should work now, I think. If not, let me know.

Comment: No go I'm afraid. Havin edited config.mk.in to integer-simple, configure --prefix=$HOME/simple then make install gives the same nonsense error message as before: "Configuring Cabal-1.12.0... ghc-cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing base >=4 && <3 && >=2 && <5". I don't know where this should be reported.

Answer (score 3):

That message,

> cabal: cannot configure base-4.4.1.0

means cabal is trying to reinstall base, or rather, fortunately it's not trying to actually do that (that's impossible, base is too tightly interwoven with the compiler, you absolutely positively cannot reinstall that). But you are trying to install something that would require reinstalling base.

The problem is that one (or more) of the packages you're trying to install depends on `integer-simple`. `base` depends on either `integer-gmp` or `integer-simple`. Both of these packages provide an implementation of the `Integer` type and some fundamental operations involving it, so you can have only one of these two. The default is `integer-gmp` because it's the one with far superior performance, and that's the one you have installed (and all[?] prebuilt binaries are built with that).

If you really need a package depending on `integer-simple`, you have to build GHC from source yourself (I recommend keeping the one with `integer-gmp` after the build nevertheless, you'd have to keep them in separate locations, though, if they're the same GHC version, e.g. the normal in ~/bin (and ~/lib), the other in ~/simple/$dir).

Building it from source is not really difficult, it does take a while, though. The procedure is

1. download the source tarball and unpack it
2. open mk/config.mk.in in an editor, change INTEGER_LIBRARY to integer-simple there and save
3. $ cd ghc-7.2.2
4. $ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/whereever/you/want/it
5. $ make && make install

Comment: Unfortunately cabal-dev install llvm returns: "cabal: cannot configure bytestring-0.9.0.2. It requires ghc-prim -any" but these are both installed There is no available version.."..I get this message with text, hledger and other packages which only depend on base.

Comment: 1. Is that the vanilla binary or a newly built with integer-simple? 2. The error message is not helpful, a frequent problem with cabal, run it with higher verbosity to get more info, in particular, why on earth would it want to install such an ancient version of bytestring, unless you typo'ed the version, in which case, why would it want to reinstall that? Run `$ ghc-pkg check` to look for broken packages.

Comment: The vanilla binary. Trying bytestring with cabal-dev install -v3 bytestring --reinstall produces: "cabal: cannot configure bytestring." and no available ghc-prim etc. As you say, cabal doesn't give any more info, even with -v3. I had just done a ghc reinstall. Tnx v. much for the assistance.

Comment: cabal itself should tell you quite a lot with `-v3`, which package versions it selects and which it discards. To not muck anything up, make it a dry-run: `$ cabal install --reinstall -v3 --dry-run bytestring`.

Comment: Have added the info in the OP.

Comment: ghc-pkg check just lists my usual haddock warnings for missing docs.

Comment: Posted build failure nonsense message to ghc trac as ticket #5765